# How to display English and Hindi records from sqlite db in HTML format in webview, Android

Tags: android, html, sqlite, webview, font-face

I am new to Android and want to write Android code to display data from SQLite database in HTML format in webview.
The database contains data in Hindi font and English font.

Actually, I want to display the song from songbook database and the database contains some lines in Hindi and some lines in English.

I am able to display the song in Hindi font only in the text view.
In webview, can't display song in the Hindi font in webviewb in html format.

Whereas I want to display song in both Hindi and English font from SQLite database in HTML format in webview.

Can anyone help me or show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with your encoding try this in your webview

```
 webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, strContent, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: This I am already using. I want to display english and Hindi simultaneously.  If you can provide me a small example to display one line of hindi and one line of english, I will be grateful to you.

Answer (score 0):

initially retrieve the hindi song from the sqlite db and then **assign that song to the string varaible** then pass the string variable in **webview.loaddata()**;

Code as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;
    private String hindiText = "पंचकूला में 25 अगस्त को हुए दंगों के बाद पुलिस ने दंगाइयों को गिरफ्तार करना शुरू किया तभी सामने गया था कि हनीप्रीत इस पूरी साजिश में शामिल है.";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.loadData(hindiText, "text/html", "UTF-8");

    }
}
```

Comment: And next to hindi line I want to display one english line. How I can display english and Hindi simultaneously. please guide me